# elasticsearch migration plugin: no useful data in response

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the migration plugin installed, can can see by doing a `plugin -l` command that it is installed.

When I hit it, however: `http://localhost:9200/_plugin/migration`

The response is rather... thin:

```
<head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/_plugin/migration/></head>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You're basically missing a slash at the end of your URL. Also what happens if you hit `http://localhost:9200/_plugin/migration/test.html`?

Comment: @Val NO. /test.html is NOT what you want for a migration analysis. See new answer posted below.

Comment: Still, I'm glad I hinted you at the solution regarding the trailing slash ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh, you need the trailing backslash...

```
http://localhost:9200/_plugin/migration/
```

Also, curl doesn't work well for it, use a browser.

The problem is that the docs here:

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-migration

Are missing the trailing backslash...